# Tracking alternatives within goal funnels

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, a-b-testing, split-testing

I honestly have no idea how to phrase this better.

I need to take a regular goal funnel tracking and make it report on a few alternatives within one of the steps.

Here's an example: back button usage. There's a built-in back button in the browser, and we have one on the site. Here's what I need to figure out: of all the situations where users returned back, how many of them used which of the two buttons. I imagine having the results on a pie chart would help.

The step with alternatives will have to be enclosed by two other steps that must be commmon for both scenarios, that way we can isolate the users who went through the alternatives.

In the example above, the first step would be triggered by a product page visit. The second step would be either clicking the back button on the site or in the browser (how to actually track that is a whole other question), and the final step would be finishing the checkout. So we take all users who were on the product page and ended up making a purchase, and try to see the percentage of how many of them used which button.

[Google Analytics Experiments](https://www.crazyegg.com/blog/ab-testing-google-analytics/) seems like an option, but it looks like the variants can be different pages with different URLs only, while I need the variants to be different Javascript events on the same page.

I'd prefer Yandex Metrika, but can use Google Analytics as well. Tried searching for [*tracking alternatives with analytics*](https://www.google.com/search?q=tracking+alternatives+with+analytics) but the results mostly cover alternatives to Google Analytics.

Comment: I tried to explain, but if something doesn't make sense, please let me know and I'll elaborate

Comment: Would the "behavior flow" report answer your questions?